# How can I run React Native app on browser?

Tags: react-native, expo

How can I run React Native app on browser?
Is expo good for do this?
is their any difference between react-native project created using `expo init AwesomeProject` and using npx `react-native init AwesomeProject`?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, yes, there is a difference between `expo init` and `npx react-native init`: using `expo init` creates a new managed expo project using the [Expo Framework](https://docs.expo.dev/).

Once you initialize a new Expo project, you can start it with `expo start` which will then allow you to run your react native project in a browser using the command `w`.